# Uninstall Oracle Java from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-8

I had installed Oracle Java following the steps described in this [link](https://www.guru99.com/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu.html).

But now I want to remove this version of Java as I am using OpenJDK for a project, how can I remove oracle java now from my Ubuntu `18.04` system?

Comment: How about trying SDKMAN: https://sdkman.io/ for switching between versions of Java?

Answer (score 0):

First, you delete the link:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk[version]/bin/java"    
sudo update-alternatives --remove "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk[version]/bin/javac"    
sudo update-alternatives --remove "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk[version]/bin/javaws"
```

Then, you can delete the package:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/jvm/jdk[version]
```

Credit to [https://askubuntu.com/questions/117543/how-to-remove-oracle-jdk/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117543/how-to-remove-oracle-jdk/164972#164972?newreg=17d7586b4542457282e0028c964dcf3b)